# GoogleMap is getting null although onMapReady is called

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm working with an android app which has tabbed view pager layout. I've to show a map into the first screen of the viewpager. The map is contained into a Fragment into an Activity (AppCompatActivity -> Fragment -> Map). The app has a service which is used to update the map when needed.

Fragment Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Inside Fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, MapViewUpdateListener {

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
```

inside `onCreateView()`:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

inside `onMapReady`

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
            theGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```

inside `MapViewUpdateListener` (using to listen location update from background service)

```
@Override
public void pointTo(Location location) {
      Marker currentLocationMarker = mGoogleMap
                .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
    }
}
```

When map is loading `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` is getting called and I'm storing `googleMap` to a global variable for future use. The problem is when `pointTo(Location location)` get called from service the `mGoogleMap` discovered null here. But `mGoogleMap` is initialized when `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` was called.

I've tried in several ways including using `MapView` instead of using `SupportMapFragment`. But didn't come up with any solution!

Any clue or workaround to fix up this problem? TIA.

**SOLUTION**

After trying in several ways finally got a stable solution. I've removed the `MapViewUpdateListener` from HomeFragment and implement a `LocalBroadCastReceiver` to receive update from the service. Actually I've removed the existing `LocalBroadCastReceiver` from `HomeActivity` and place it into `HomeFragment`. When `LocalBroadCastReceiver` get fired in `HomeFragment` I can use the existing `mGoogleMap` without any NPE.

But still, I don't have any idea why location update passing through interface get NPE for the instance variables. I guess, there may have some problem the way I was initializing `HomeFragment` as `MapViewUpdateListener`. May be the `HomeFragment` object I get by typecasting return a new `HomeFragment` instead of existing one!!! (But it's hard to believe that can happen!)

Comment: "The problem is when pointTo(Location location) get called from service" -- a service cannot call a method on an activity or fragment, unless you are doing something wrong. Where *exactly* is this listener, how *exactly* is it being called, and how are you ensuring that it will not be called before `onMapReady()` is called?

Comment: @CommonsWare Actually, `HomeActivity` is getting the location update from `Service` using `LocalBroadCastReceiver`. Then `HomeActivity` is passing the location update using `MapViewUpdateListener`'s `pointTo(Location location)` method to the Fragment. Service is not using Activity/Fragment method directly.

Comment: OK. What are you doing to ensure that `pointTo()` will not be called before `onMapReady()`?

Comment: I'm not doing anything special here. I've just debug and logged in logcat and found that `onMapReady()` is getting called before `pointTo ()` is called.

Comment: @CommonsWare any suggestion?

Comment: Either you have two fields name `mGoogleMap`, or you are setting `mGoogleMap` to null, or you have two separate objects with the `mGoogleMap` field.

Answer (score 0):

You have race condition here. Try to set marker inside `pointTo` method (you are doing it already) but have `null` check for `mGoogleMap` being `null`.
Also, in case google Map is ready after you receive location update (`onMapReady` gets called after `pointTo`) update marker inside `onMapRead`y (with variables `latitude` and `longitude` when pointTo method was called.

So, you pointTo method could look like this:

```
   @Override
 public void pointTo(Location location) {
        if(mGoogleMap!=null){
        Marker currentLocationMarker = mGoogleMap
                  .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                  .position(new 
                   LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()))
                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                 .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
     }
 }
     else{
       latitude=location.latitude;//or whatever property is called
       longitude=location.longitude;;//or whatever property is called
      }
 }
```

In map ready do this:

```
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    theGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

   if(latitude!=null && longitude!=null){

      //Insert marker here on map because we have map ready and latitude and longitude also
   }
 }
```

Comment: `onMapReady()` get called only once and `pointTo()` is get called whenever new location is available. In case of `mGoogleMap` is null in `pointTo()`, the `onMapReady()` will not be called twice. So there is no way to use the lat, lang in `onMapReady()` that was stored in `pointTo()` method.

Comment: googleMap is null inside onMapReady? if is that happening than I have no idea